# How to convert sql to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

Have specific SQL query need to convert to Laravel eloquent, I already converted getting error, does everyone help me pls?

my sql

```
select 
    `d1`.*, `a1`.`user_uuid` as `activity_user` 
from 
    `directors` as `d1` 
left join 
    `activities` as `a1` 
on `a1`.`entity_uuid` = `d1`.`uuid` 
and `a1`.`created_at` = (
    select 
        max(`created_at`) 
    from
        `activities` as `a2`
    where `a2`.`entity_uuid`=`d1`.`uuid`
)
where `a1`.`user_uuid`='4f858f46-2d7e-41c8-a185-c9c4a4b506d1'
group by `a1`.`entity_uuid` 
order by `d1`.`updated_at` 
desc limit 100;
```

and my laravel eloquent

```
DB::table('directors')
->select('directors.*')
->leftJoin('activities',function($join) {
    $join->on('a1.entity_uuid','=','directors.uuid')
    ->on('a1.created_at','=',function($query) {
        $query->from('activities')
            ->select(DB::raw('max'('activities.created_at'))
            ->where('activities.entity_uuid','=',DB::raw('d1.uuid'));
    });
}
->where('activities.user_uuid','=','4f858f46-2d7e-41c8-a185-c9c4a4b506d1')
->groupBy('activities.entity_uuid')
->orderBy('directors.updated_at','desc')
->get();
```

the error what I get

```
TypeError: stripos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, Closure given in file C:\xampp\htdocs\crmMembers\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Grammar.php on line 62
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for everyone, it solved

just change double ->on to ->where and works perfect

```
->where('a1.created_at', '=', function($q){$q->from('activities as a2')
                                                ->select(DB::raw('max(`a2`.`created_at`)'))
                                                ->where('a2.entity_uuidm', '=', DB::raw('`d1`.`uuid`'));
                                        });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your Laravel DB query should be like this

```
DB::table('directors')->select('directors.*', 'activities.user_uuid as activity_user')
    ->leftJoin('activities',function($join) {
        $join->on('a1.entity_uuid','=','directors.uuid')
             ->on('a1.created_at','=',function($query) {
                  $query->from('activities')
                        ->select(DB::raw('max(created_at)')
                        ->where('activities.entity_uuid','=',DB::raw('d1.uuid'));
               });
    })
    ->where('activities.user_uuid','=','4f858f46-2d7e-41c8-a185-c9c4a4b506d1')
    ->groupBy('activities.entity_uuid')
    ->orderBy('directors.updated_at','desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: already solved but thanks for answer